# Arranging row text based on the header using boostrap or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, sorting

I have this kind of table using boostrap. I wanted to sort them from ASC or DESC after clicking the header. I search for ordering and sorting in boostrap but it is not the thing I want to achieve. Ordering is for moving things and sorting is for selecting and removing based on selection.

```js
$('#header > div').on('click', function() {
  var $label = $(this).find('label');
  // get column number
  var $filter = $label.attr('data-name') == 'name' ? 1 : 2;
  // set the toggle asc/desc flag
  var $sort = $label.attr('data-sort') || -1;
  $label.attr('data-sort', -$sort);
  $sort = -$sort;

  $('#header').nextAll('.row').sort(function(a, b) {

    var c = $(a).find('div:nth-child(' + $filter + ') label').text();
    var d = $(b).find('div:nth-child(' + $filter + ') label').text();
    if ($filter === 1) { // filter strings
      if (c == d)
        return 0;
      else if (c > d)
        return 1 * $sort;
      else if (c < d)
        return -1 * $sort;
    } else { // filter numbers
      return (+c - +d) * $sort;
    }
  }).insertAfter($('#header'));
});

// initial sorting
$('#header > div:first-child').trigger('click')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row " id="header">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small" data-name="name" data-filtering="true">Name</label></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small" data-name="id" data-filtering="true">ID</label></h6>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues fullname">A </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues id">4</label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues fullname">B </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues id">3</label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues fullname">C </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues id">2</label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues fullname">D </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues id">1</label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues ">Total </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small  id"></label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>
```

> Is there a function on how to achieve my goal.

**Goal**

When clicking on name it should make the row arrange from A to D or D to A 
Same as the number as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would normally use some *data binding* plugins like `angular.js` but here is a solution using jquery:

1. First you get the *column number* to target the `name` and `id` columns
2. Next we set / get the *ascending* or *descending* flag on the column
3. Now we user `sort()` for all the *rows* and *append* them back to the DOM.

See demo below:

```js
$('#header > div').on('click', function() {
  var $label = $(this).find('label');
  // get column number
  var $filter = $label.attr('data-name') == 'name' ? 1 : 2;
  // set the toggle asc/desc flag
  var $sort = $label.attr('data-sort') || -1;
  $label.attr('data-sort', -$sort);
  $sort = -$sort;

  $('#header').nextUntil('#total').sort(function(a, b) {

    var c = $(a).find('div:nth-child(' + $filter + ') label').text();
    var d = $(b).find('div:nth-child(' + $filter + ') label').text();
    if ($filter === 1) { // filter strings
      if (c == d)
        return 0;
      else if (c > d)
        return 1 * $sort;
      else if (c < d)
        return -1 * $sort;
    } else { // filter numbers
      return (+c - +d) * $sort;
    }
  }).insertAfter($('#header'));
});

// initial sorting
$('#header > div:first-child').trigger('click')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row " id="header">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small" data-name="name" data-filtering="true">Name</label></h6>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small" data-name="id" data-filtering="true">ID</label></h6>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues fullname">A </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues id">4</label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues fullname">B </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues id">12</label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues fullname">C </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues id">2</label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues fullname">D </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues id">1</label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>



<div class="row" id="total">
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small newvalues ">Total </label></h6> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-1 table-bordered text-sm-center">
    <h6><label class="col-form-label small  id"></label></h6> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: where is `.attr('data-sort')` or should it be `data-filtering` ?

Comment: also do i need to convert to in for numerical convert? when i have value like `10 or 12` it sort like `1,10,12,2,3,4` which is not  correct.

Comment: @Martin `data-sort` same functionality as `data-filtering` except that it uses numbers instead of `true` or `false`... I'll check the sort issue now and will fix it...

Comment: also another question if i add more columns will this still be ok as i understand `var $filter = $label.attr('data-name') == 'name' ? 1 : 2;` will just selecting first column or second so i can use `this` context to get this one

Comment: I guess it is better to have the `$filter` - the column number as an attribute to account for the case when there are more than 2 columns...

Comment: that is better since the columns will be static the index wont change. it column number right not index so filter will start with 1 not zero

Comment: yes, you are right, it is not index and will start from 1... also note that I've used `if ($filter === 1) {` condition to check if I'm sorting *string* or a *number* - you can add that as a *data attribute* too I guess...

Comment: can you check last update i cant figure why it appends outside of table on first click and second it looks ok

Comment: @Martin please check the update - have replace `nextAll` with `nextUntil` method - is that what you look for?

Comment: yes tried it looks like the js wasnt update in my browser that is why it didnt work on me first happy coding mate :)

Comment: mate i have encountered a problem with comparing zero `0` value for number and blank `""` values for string. When i have these values it sort of  dynamically add other rows. I will update my example.

Comment: it looks like i cant replicate the problem i am having because i am adding my values dynamically in my project.